# SWT Scale - add more bars

Tags: java, swt, composite

Is it possible to have more than one selection (bars) on the scale component? 
Or could someone please suggest me another component that I can use instead?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Opal project](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/) has a widget called [`RangeSlider`](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/RangeSlider).

This lets you use 2 "bars". I don't know of anything that has more and I can't think of any scenario where you would need more than 2.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks @Baz for the fast answer.I want to do something similar with the Gradient color picker from Photoshop if you are familiar. The idea is that you can add on the scale as many bars as you wish in order to create the gradient (http://artist.tizag.com/screencaptures/photoshop/toolcaptures/gradienttool/gradienttooleditor.gif) Thanks again!

Comment: @EdwinT. The basic SWT widget set does not contain anything that could be used for this purpose and I'm afraid I don't know of any other third party widget either...

Comment: @EdwinT. Found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ThumbSliderExample2.htm) using Swing/AWT. Looks like you can use an arbitrary number of bars with this. you might be able to use it with the SWT/AWT brigde...

Comment: @EdwinT. Yes, definitely do that. I guess there might be more people in the future looking for a solution.

Comment: the Swing/AWT component works fine for what I had in mind. Thanks!!